# How to check array of object having same id and null in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object

Given array of objects `arr1` and `arr2`

check every object in array

`taskId` of `arr1` and `id` of `arr2` are equal,
and

and `null` taskid,  remove and returning the arr2 values in javascript

if both array of object has same id and taskid, if arr2 has null value in taskid, return reamining object arrary in arr2 using javascript

tried

const result = arr2.map(async task => {!arr1.some(arr1 => arr1.taskId === task.id)})

```
var arr1 =[
  {
    "name": "sample task",
    "memberIds": [
      981,
      983
    ],
    "dueOn": "2022-08-31",
    "taskId": 10
  },
  {
    "name": "skills one more",
    "memberIds": [
      981,
      983,
      984
    ],
    "dueOn": "2022-08-31",
    "taskId": null
  },
  {
    "name": "new task one",
    "memberIds": [
      982,
      983
    ],
    "dueOn": "2022-08-2",
    "taskId": 15
  },
]
var arr2 =[
  {
    "id": 10,
    "createdAt": "2022-08-02T09:10:07.000Z",
    "createdBy": 21,
    "updatedAt": null,
    "updatedBy": null,
    "statusId": 6207,
    "caseGoalId": 11,
    "name": "sample task",
    "dueOn": "2022-08-31"
  }
]
```

Expected Output

```
 [{
    "name": "new task one",
    "memberIds": [
      982,
      983
    ],
    "dueOn": "2022-08-2",
    "taskId": 15
  }]
```

Comment: There was a wrong in my answer condition, please check again, I think it works now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `filter` `arr1`, and on each `item` inside, you need to check if exist in the `arr2` and `return` if it exist or if the item `id` equal `null`

```js
var arr1 =[
  {
    "name": "sample task",
    "memberIds": [
      981,
      983
    ],
    "dueOn": "2022-08-31",
    "taskId": 10
  },
  {
    "name": "skills one more",
    "memberIds": [
      981,
      983,
      984
    ],
    "dueOn": "2022-08-31",
    "taskId": null
  },
  {
    "name": "new task one",
    "memberIds": [
      982,
      983
    ],
    "dueOn": "2022-08-2",
    "taskId": 15
  },
]
var arr2 =[
  {
    "id": 10,
    "createdAt": "2022-08-02T09:10:07.000Z",
    "createdBy": 21,
    "updatedAt": null,
    "updatedBy": null,
    "statusId": 6207,
    "caseGoalId": 11,
    "name": "sample task",
    "dueOn": "2022-08-31"
  }
]

const result = arr1.filter(item => !(item.taskId === null || arr2.some(i => i.id === item.taskId)))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

There must be some missing information. There's no way to get the expected output with these requirements. Your taskId's from arr1 are 10, null, & 15. The only id in arr2 is 10 therefore you would never get this output:

```
[{
   "name": "new task one",
   "memberIds": [
     982,
     983
   ],
   "dueOn": "2022-08-2",
   "taskId": 15
}]
```

but instead get:

```
[{
    "name": "sample task",
    "memberIds": [
        981,
        983
    ],
    "dueOn": "2022-08-31",
    "taskId": 10
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a way you can do it...

Time complexity O(N^2)

```
const check = (arr1, arr2) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
          if (arr1[i] === null) {
            return [...arr2];
          }
          if (arr1[i].taskId !== null && arr1[i].taskId === arr2[j].id) {
            return { ...arr1[i] };
          }
    
          // ...more checks...
        }
      }

};
```